# Webscraping data from a table but the tbody tag is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to webscrape the data table from this site:
https://fl511.com/list/events/traffic?start=0&length=25&filters%5B0%5D%5Bi%5D=5&filters%5B0%5D%5Bs%5D=Incidents&order%5Bi%5D=8&order%5Bdir%5D=asc

But unfortunately, when I print out the table it doesn't return the tbody tag (which the information is stored in). All the other tags are shown. Is there a workaround to this?

```
url = Request(
    url,
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    )
webpage = urlopen(url).read()

table = soup.find_all('table')
print(table)
```

Comment: Perhaps the page uses javascript to load the tbody and its contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded from external source via Javascript. You can use this example how to load the data:

```
import json
import requests

data = {
    "draw": 1,
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": None,
            "name": "",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": False,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "title": "",
            "visible": True,
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "region",
            "name": "region",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": True,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "county",
            "name": "county",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": True,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "roadwayName",
            "name": "roadwayName",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": True,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "direction",
            "name": "direction",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": True,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "type",
            "name": "type",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": True,
            "search": {"value": "Incidents", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "severity",
            "name": "severity",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": True,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "description",
            "name": "description",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": False,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "startTime",
            "name": "startTime",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": True,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": "lastUpdated",
            "name": "lastUpdated",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": True,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
        {
            "data": 10,
            "name": "",
            "searchable": False,
            "orderable": False,
            "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
            "isUtcDate": False,
            "isCollection": False,
        },
    ],
    "order": [{"column": 8, "dir": "asc"}],
    "start": 0,
    "length": 25,
    "search": {"value": "", "regex": False},
}

url = "https://fl511.com/List/GetData/traffic"


data = requests.post(url, json=data).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for i, d in enumerate(data["data"], 1):
    print(i, d["description"])

print()
print("Records total:", data["recordsTotal"])
print("Records filtered:", data["recordsFiltered"])
```

Prints:

```
1 Crash in Highlands County on US-27 South, at Lake Josephine Dr. Right lane blocked. Last updated at 04:24 PM.
2 Emergency vehicles in Highlands County on US-27 North, at Lake Josephine Dr. Right lane blocked. Last updated at 04:25 PM.
3 Crash in Manatee County on US-41 North, at Pearl Ave. All lanes blocked. Last updated at 04:29 PM.
4 Crash in Polk County on I-4 East, beyond CR-557. 2 Left lanes blocked. Last updated at 04:32 PM.
5 Emergency vehicles in Manatee County on US-41 South, at Pearl Ave. Left lane blocked. Last updated at 04:35 PM.
6 Crash in Miami-Dade County on I-195 East, beyond North Miami Ave. Right lane blocked. Last updated at 05:03 PM.
7 Crash in Santa Rosa County on I-10 East, ramp to Exit 22 (SR-281/Avalon Blvd). Right shoulder blocked. Last updated at 05:05 PM.
8 Emergency vehicles in Santa Rosa County on I-10 West, at Exit 22 (SR-281/Avalon Blvd). Left shoulder blocked. Last updated at 05:02 PM.
9 Multi-vehicle crash in Duval County on I-295 E South, before Between Atlantic Blvd/St Johns Bluff Rd. Left shoulder blocked. Last updated at 05:30 PM.

Records total: 93
Records filtered: 9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I hope you don't mind me asking, how did you find the URL to where to get the data from? And how did you get all the information for the filter?

Comment: @Kab2k You can inspect all requests that the page is doing in Firefox developer tools->Network Tab (Chrome has something similar).

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what you mean for the URL. But how is it with the filter? Because I couldn't find any jsonfile for that?